# sknn multi layer perceptron classifier

Tags: python, neural-network

I am using the following neural net classifier in python

```
from sknn.mlp import Layer,Classifier

nn = mlp.Classifier(
            layers=[
                mlp.Layer("Tanh", units=n_feat/8),
                mlp.Layer("Sigmoid", units=n_feat/16),
                mlp.Layer("Softmax", units=n_targets)],
            n_iter=50,
            n_stable=10,
            batch_size=25,
            learning_rate=0.002,
            learning_rule="momentum",
            valid_size=0.1,
            verbose=1)
```

which is working just fine.My question is that how to proceed if I require for example 100,200 or 500 hidden layers? Do I have to specify each layer here manually or someone has better Idea in python for MLP?

Comment: have a question, I am pretty new in the Neural Network and trying to learn it. Is this nn representing (input layer, 1 hidden ly and 1 output) or (1 input ly, 3 hidden ly, 1 output layer) structure ?                                                                             `layers=[
                mlp.Layer("Tanh", units=n_feat/8),
                mlp.Layer("Sigmoid", units=n_feat/16),
                mlp.Layer("Softmax", units=n_targets)],`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create some loop-based mechanism to build the list of layers I suppose, but there's a bigger issue here.  A standard MLP with hundreds of layers is likely to be *extremely* expensive to train - both in terms of computational speed as well as memory usage.  MLPs typically only have one or two hidden layers, or occasionally a few more.  But for problems that can truly benefit from more hidden layers, it becomes important to incorporate some of the lessons learned in the field of [deep learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_learning).  For example, for object classification on images, using all fully-connected layers is incredibly inefficient, because you're interested in identifying spatially-local patterns, and therefore interactions between spatially-distant pixels or regions is largely noise.  (This is a perfect case for using a deep convolutional neural net.)

Although some *very* deep networks have been created, it's worth pointing out that even Google's very powerful Inception-v3 model is only 42-layers deep.  Anyway, if you're interested in building deep models, I'd recommend reading this [Deep Learning book](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/).  From what I've read of it, it seems to be a very good introduction.  Hope that helps!